# Unable to click on button of a search result with Selenium / Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I'm using Selenium and coding in Python.

I'm having trouble getting my script to click on the first button (`id=ita_form_button_LinkButton_0`), which is the first available option and the cheapest option. I get this error message instead: `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'send_click'`

This is the code that I have:

```
element_result = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        lambda driver : driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id*=ita_form_button_LinkButton")
)
element_result[0].send_click()
```

The idea is to always click on the first available option (button) as that is always the cheapest option, but it weirdly wouldn't click. Would you guys know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [`send_keys`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click), [`click`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) in [`WebElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement), but no `send_click`.

Replace following line:

```
element_result[0].send_click()
```

with:

```
element_result[0].click()
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the help!